# Use build time environment variable in Docker CMD

Tags: docker, environment-variables

I have a Dockerfile:

```
...

COPY ${JAR_FILENAME}-*.jar /${JAR_FILENAME}.jar

...

CMD java -jar $(echo /${JAR_FILENAME}.jar)
```

And I am building the image with: `docker build --build-arg JAR_FILENAME='some-file' -t some-name:tag`

But when I run the container, I get:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile /.jar
```

How do I pass the environment variables during the build time to my `CMD` command so that I can run `java -jar some-file.jar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use an ENV, setting it to the value of the ARG. An ENV is nearly identical to an ARG, but gets saved to the image metadata and therefore persists to when you run the container.

```
...

ARG JAR_FILENAME=app.jar
ENV JAR_FILENAME=${JAR_FILENAME}
COPY ${JAR_FILENAME}-*.jar /${JAR_FILENAME}.jar

...

CMD java -jar /${JAR_FILENAME}.jar
```

Note that users of the image can alter ENV values, and it may be easier to just set the jar in the image to a well known name:

```
...

COPY ${JAR_FILENAME}-*.jar /app.jar

...

CMD java -jar /app.jar
```

Comment: I was blind. Why didn't I use a generic filename like `app.jar` in the first place... It's always good to know how I can do it anyways, so thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `ARG` construct in Docker file to pass in build time arguments from command line.

Read the docs at : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. This is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I see, got trigger happy - I would agree with @BMitch 's answer.